# How to disable backups for custom widgets in Vaadin 7

Tags: javascript, java, vaadin, vaadin7

In my Vaadin application a custom widget which extends AbstractJavaScriptComponent has several files as follows. These files are available in browser:

- Comp1Html.js.exe
- Comp1Html_bak.js
- Comp1Htmlold

Are these bak and old files required? Also, how to remove these unwanted files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to preserve all files that are directly referenced through e.g. a `@JavaScript` annotation or indirectly referenced by e.g. being included from another script file. The exact details on that is highly depending on the specifics of this particular component.

The easiest way to find out which files are actually needed might be to temporary put a copy of all the files somewhere else and then try removing each file and checking if everything still seems to work.

Comment: Seems the Comp1Html_bak.js and Comp1Htmlold are backup files. can we stop this by setting cache time to 0?

Comment: What cache time?

Comment: My problem is these files available in browser cache and can be downloaded by the url. so this is a security threat. hence required to rremove these files after using

Comment: Why is it a security threat that old backup versions of the same scripts are available? If the file is already in someone's browser cache, then it might stay there until the original expiration time unless it was originally served with `must-revalidate`. Changing the cache time will only prevent the files from ending up in the cache of more browsers, but for that purpose it's even better to just remove the files.